# Hive sql find out how many common customer in each country

Tags: sql, hive, set

I have a table called custtable, have 3 columns custid,country,date
there are 5 countrise in country: 'CH','US', 'UK','FR' and 'GE'
I hope have elegent query to find out how many unique [custid] in 5 countrise.

currently, I can use subquery and temporary table to find the overlapping set, but any suggestions for a more simple way.

here is my way to find out the overlapping for 2 countries and then I need to do another subquery

```
   with t1 AS
(SELECT DISTINCT [custid]
       FROM custtable
       where date>20140101
       and country='CH'),

t2 as 
 (SELECT DISTINCT [custid]
       FROM custtable
       where date>20140101
       and country='FR'),
t3 AS
(SELECT DISTINCT [custid]
       FROM custtable
       where date>20140101
       and country='US'),

t4 as 
 (SELECT DISTINCT [custid]
       FROM custtable
       where date>20140101
       and country='UK')

select count (distinct t1.custid) 
from t1 
inner join t3
on (t1.custid=t3.custid)
inner join t2
on (t1.custid=t2.custid)
inner join t4
on (t1.custid=t4.custid)
```

thank you for any input

Comment: The title is: *how many common customer in each country* and in the question: *how many unique [custid] in 5 countries*. Clarify what you want and better post sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a better way is to count how many distinct countries each `custid` has and filter count >= 5, e.g.,

```
with count_table as (
select custid, count(distinct country) as cnt
  from custtable
   where date>20140101
)
select custid, cnt
  from count_table
 where cnt >= 5
```

then count your `cusid`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNTRY
     , COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTID)   AS CNT
  FROM CUSTTABLE 
GROUP BY COUNTRY
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want customers in all five countries:

```
select custid
from custtable
where date > 20140101
group by custid
having count(distinct country) = 5;
```

If you want those particular five countries (as your query suggests):

```
select custid
from custtable
where date > 20140101 and
      country in ('CH','US', 'UK','FR', 'GE')
group by custid
having count(distinct country) = 5;
```